# how can i get alert of data submitted successfully from using servlet,js,html,mysql remote server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, servlets

Below is my code, I want to handle the response send by server, That is data submitted successfully: I want to make an alert prompt data submitted successfully if it is in correct form

```
<script src="js/jquery.serializeJSON.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform" id="myform"> 
<div class="form-group">
<label for="fullName">Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="fullName" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="email">Email:</label>
<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="subject">Subject:</label>
<input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="mark">Mark:</label>
<input type="number" name="mark" class="form-control">
</form>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success "     id="submitform">Submit</button>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submitform").click(function(e)
{
var MyForm = JSON.stringify($("#myform").serializeJSON());
console.log(MyForm);
$.ajax(
{
url : "<your url>",
type: "POST",
data : MyForm,
});

});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the success and error callback functions for handling respective response

```
 $.ajax(
 {
 url : "<your url>",
 type: "POST",
data : MyForm,
success:function(data,status){

   console.log(data);
   //alert ur data here by checking data
},
error:function(err){
   console.log(err);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If your return like bool result from server response then check in success if response is true.

```
   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<your url>",
            data:formdata
            success: function (response, textStatus, xhr)
            {
                if (response == true)
                {
                    alert("success");
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("failed")
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                       alert("error")
            }
        });
```

Comment: from where i get response i dont know much more i am new in ajax

Comment: whenever you post data using ajax it calls your method that you provided in you ajax url and your method return type for example is boolean then it return either true or false.it means success or failed like its called your response.